# Python dataframe concat utility creating a cartesian product like data set when uploading multiple dataframes created by multiple CSV files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner in Python, so feel free to treat me like a 5 yr old :)

Using Python 2.7.16
Objective: load multiple csv files in to one dataframe. 
CSV files structure : 3 columns - filename, symbol, counter. No index or column headers.

Problem: Files seem to be concatenated horizontally . The resulting DF should ave only 3 columns and several hundred rows from all the CSV file that we uploaded. Instead we get 1573 columns and several million rows.

```
files=glob.glob('/my/data/folder/*.csv')
files=list(filter(lambda file: os.stat(file).st_size>0, files))
df=pd.concat(map(functools.partial(pd.read_csv, sep=','), files))

>>> print len(df.columns)
1573

>>> print len(df.index)
3774731
```

input file sample :

```
/my/data/folder/a1,O:ZZZ\17J20\32.0,339
/my/data/folder/b1,O:ZZZ\17J20\34.0,262
/my/data/folder/c1,O:ZZZ\17J20\36.0,200
/my/data/folder/d1,O:ZZZ\17J20\38.0,129
/my/data/folder/e1,O:ZZZ\17P21\25.0,155
/my/data/folder/f1,O:ZZZ\17P21\26.0,38

field 1: full file path & name
field 2: string
field 3: integer
```

Comment: Are you sure all of the files contain just those 3 columns? Your code works as expected for me.

Comment: yes, all files have 3 comma separated values:

Comment: Why are you using Python 2? Can you explain what the code is meant to do? Why the `filter(lambda file: os.stat(file).st_size>0, files)` ? It would be good if you could share a [mcve], or at least an example of the data.

Comment: i get the same results in 3.2

Comment: @babaji _i get the same results in 3.2_ I don't think the issue is related to the version of Python/Pandas, It was more of a general question. Also, please see the rest of the comment I made above.

Comment: The code is simply meant to line up (concat) all csv files vertically. The filter & lambda function is used to clear out any files that are empty, I was getting no-data exceptions for empty (0 byte) csv files. Hope this clarifies